# How to call an rest api from word press website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have one word press website and from there I want to call one rest api. This api is in my cloud based server. In how many ways I can do this?

Comment: This is a a broad question. Do you have an example of the data you want to get and show? Something you have tried? At a high level, using AJAX (frontend) & cURL (backend) would accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ From your SO account score it's clear you haven't checked out the Help Center yet. You should take a moment to do this & find out more about how this site works. Visit the section on what type of questions are acceptable on this site >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking